# How do I perform an IDF calculation?

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining, information-retrieval

How do I perform an IDF calculation? I am uncertain as to whether IDF should be calculated in per-class level or for the entire document set (that contains multiple classes).

Comment: to clarify...IDF refers to Inverse Document Frequency, correct?

Comment: Yes. IDF refers to Inverse Document Frequency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Inverse Document Frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) should be computed for the entire training set.

IDF quantifies the level of information that each word carries for the dataset of interest and that concept is independent of the classes/tags.  Potentially, you could use the exact same IDFs for every classification problem on English documents. However, it is expected that you will get better results if you compute IDFs for the type of documents you are working on: different weights are assigned to words if the corpus are News different if it's cooking recipes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. To confirm, So if I have classes "News" and "Cooking", I have to find IDF separately for class "News" and class "Cooking" to get better results .. Correct?

Comment: No, as I said "IDF should be computed for the entire training set". In the future, in some totally different project, where you have brand new data, you have to recompute IDFs for that project. You need to compute IDFs for each corpus not for each class in the corpus.